# Issue With 3 Monitors

Tags: 11.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I have a fresh install of **11.04** (reformatted etc) and I am having problems with a 3rd monitor. I'm running 2 video cards and the default NVidia drivers. I let the drivers generate my xorg.conf because still somewhat a n00b :)

I have no issue with the 2 working monitors. They are setup as TwinView which may or may not be best but I would prefer to avoid running Xinerama because I fear I would no longer be able to use Unity. Long story short, **no known issues with the 2 monitors that are on the same video card**.

**The 3rd monitor appears to have no window manager**. I have no launch bar, no panels and when I right click -> new file gedit opens and there are no File / Edit / Tools ... options, nor is the title bar visible (with close, minimize, maximize). If I try to write anything in the text editor, it writes the text to one of the other, working, screens (Almost as if the window on the **3rd monitor never receives focus**). My xorg.conf file is posted below -- please let me know of any other files that would be helpful. **I really appreciate any advice**!

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 270.29  (buildd@roseapple)  Fri Feb 25 14:43:24 UTC 2011

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" RightOf "Screen1"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "ProView/EMC/PTS"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh     60.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL E1910H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9400 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400 GS"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, CRT-1: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0; 1366x768 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two monitors running Separate X screens, one of them is vertical and I have this same issue.  I can get a window manager to run by issuing from a terminal on the primary display `DISPLAY=:0.1 unity --replace`. So you can get up and running by finding out what your third display's identity is and replacing the `:0.1` in the command above.