# Nvidia GTX 590, 3 Monitors 12.10 64bit

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit and have Nvidia GTX 590 Connected to 3 monitors, I cannot for the life of me get all 3 working, I can get 2 running in dual but not 3rd.

Spent about 1 week still no joy.

Can anyone with similar config help me?

Comment: Hi there. Did you try searching on the website? For example, http://askubuntu.com/questions/87749/3-monitors-on-a-gt-430 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/39436/issue-with-3-monitors might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

These cards are still only capable of doing 2 displays at once :-(

I have the same "problem".

The 6xx-cards now are able to do 3 or more monitors.